# Touchpad and external USB mouse are periodically unresponsive on new install of Win 10 on HP Pavilion

Tags: windows-10, laptop, mouse, touchpad

Touchpad and external USB mouse are periodically unresponsive on new install of Win 10 on HP Pavilion Notebook. Moving the mouse continuously results in smooth movement on screen for about 1 second and then the motion stops for about 0.5 sec. Tried various fixes suggested for jerky mouse movement (eg https://windowsreport.com/mouse-lag-windows-10/?amp) but none have worked. Task Manager shows periodic spike for CPU use, with System apparently responsible.
The rotating dots shown for long-duration events periodically stop rotating as well.

Comment: New installation: have you complete *all* Windows Updates? Likely, there are updates pending.

Comment: Windows says it is up to date. Another symptom is that the blue trace for CPU use (which I believe indicates available processor power) in Resource Monitor has periodic dips below 100%, whereas on another Win 10 laptop (working OK) it is flat at 100%.

Comment: Turned out that updates were available - have now applied them restarted and problem is still there.

Comment: Just finished re-installing Windows 10 and the problem is still there

Comment: I think the problem is that some part of the Windows OS is running periodically at very high priority and blocking response to mouse movement. Looking at the System task in Resource Monitor it runs continuously and has spikes of CPU use that seem to roughly correspond with times when the mouse is frozen and the 'endless circle of dots' stops rotating.

Comment: Another possibility is indexing. On a new installation, if you "Allow files on this drive to have contents indexed...", it may take some hours to build the index. You mention using Task manager, but don't mention the process on the Detail tab using CPU... and also view the disk I/O there.

Comment: No disk I/O evident, and after being on for 8 hours or so the CPU use still shows periodic spikes so I don't think the OS is busy doing indexing.